# Google Analytics with GTM; is it possible that data will be duplicated?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm fairly new to Google Tag Manager, in the past I've just fired events straight to Google Analytics. What I'm wondering is this; is it possible that, if you use Google Analytics alongside Google Analytics tags in GTM, can you get duplicate data in Google Analytics?

For instance, let's say I have a Pageview tag in GTM, as well as GA on the webpage as normal. Would this count as two pageviews? (ie. one from standard GA, one from the GTM tag)

I've looked around for an answer, but maybe it's just a stupid question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both track to the same property you'd get two pageviews in that Ga property.

However there is a good chance that both pageviews would end up in different sessions; GTM creates a random name for the Google Analytics tracker, while the tracker within the page would track to the standard tracker (t0; [read about naming trackers here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#naming_trackers)), unless configured otherwise.

IMO it is not a good idea to mix GTM and inline trackers with the same property, since it's hard to be sure that both use the same configuration. And yes, your pageview will be counted twice.

Comment: Thanks for the help; it seems best to stick with Google Analytics in that case

Comment: @OliverRadini I recommend sticking to GTM actually; it's a really easy to use system, and much less complicated than directly coding.

Comment: I'm with @JBrazier here - if you can rather remove the static code than the GTM version, as this makes updates and maintenance rather more convenient.

Comment: @J Brazier @Eike Pierstorff  Thanks both! My main concern is losing the data that GA currently provides. For instance, how well does GTM capture information like bounce rate, time on page etc? I would be anxious to make the switch and then start losing data. Further, are there any differences in how stats like pageviews are measured? Any advice on this would be much appreciated.